# Best practice for using the 'volatile' keyword in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

Since upgrading our development and build environments from VS2008 to VS2012, I am confused about the implications of using the `volatile` keyword in our legacy codebase (it's quite extensive as there is a much copied pattern for managing threads from the "old" days).

Microsoft has the following remarks in the VS2012 documentation:

> If you are familiar with the C# **volatile** keyword, or familiar with the behavior of **volatile** in earlier versions of Visual C++, be aware that the C++11 ISO Standard **volatile** keyword is different and is supported in Visual Studio when the `/volatile:iso` compiler option is specified. (For ARM, it's specified by default). The **volatile** keyword in C++11 ISO Standard code is to be used only for hardware access; do not use it for inter-thread communication. For inter-thread communication, use mechanisms such as `std::atomic<T>` from the C++ Standard Template Library.

It goes on to say:

> When the `/volatile:ms` compiler option is used—by default when architectures other than ARM are targeted—the compiler generates extra code to maintain ordering among references to volatile objects in addition to maintaining ordering to references to other global objects.

I take this to mean, that our existing code won't break but won't necessarily be portable (not a problem for us).

However, it does raise these questions, on which I would like some advice, if possible:

1. Should we remove uses of `volatile` qualifiers in our our code and replace with C++11 ISO Standard compliant equivalents, even though we would not port the code away from MS?
2. If we don't do the above, is there any downside?

I appreciate that this is not really a specific programming problem but we're embarking on some quite major refactoring and I would like to be able to offer some sensible guidelines for this work.

Comment: Please fix it. Otherwise, some of your coworkers will, later in their life, become my coworkers and I don't want to have to teach them that "volatile != thread-safe even though you've been doing it for years".

Comment: I'll do my best - but "later in their life" most of my co-workers will be retired, along with me ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If you have the time for it. The benefits are not that great - C++11 atomics may allow more precise control over precisely what kind of synchronization you need, and have more clearly defined semantics, which may allow the compiler to optimize the code better.
2. In theory, but very very unlikely, a future version of the compiler might drop support for the MS-style volatile completely. Or one day you actually do want to port away from the MS compiler, even if you stay on Windows. If you're now doing refactoring, that might be a good time to do the work of replacing the volatiles with atomics, saving you from doing the work in the future.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian - we're thinking along the same lines, which is good, I'm just wary because refactoring the `volatile` bits to use atomics would tend to lead me to review our multi-threading code more generally, so I'm looking for the "good place to stop" and having trouble seeing it! +1 for the advice.