# How to control thread lifetime using C++11 atomics

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, atomic

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16340899/2065121), I'd like to know what's the recommended approach we should take to replace the very common pattern we have in legacy code.

We have plenty of places where a primary thread is spawing one or more background worker threads and periodically pumping out some work for them to do, using a suitably synchronized queue. So the general pattern for a worker thread will look like this:

There will be an event `HANDLE` and a `bool` defined somewhere (usually as member variables) -

```
HANDLE hDoSomething = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
volatile bool bEndThread = false;
```

Then the worker thread function waits for the event to be signalled before doing work, but checks for a termination request inside the main loop -

```
unsigned int ThreadFunc(void *pParam)
{
    // typical legacy implementation of a worker thread
    while (true)
    {
        // wait for event
        WaitForSingleObject(hDoSomething, INFINITE);

        // check for termination request
        if (bEndThread) break;

        // ... do background work ...
    }

    // normal termination
    return 0;
}
```

The primary thread can then give some work to the background thread like this -

```
// ... put some work on a synchronized queue ...

// pulse worker thread to do the work
SetEvent(hDoSomething);
```

And it can finally terminate the worker thread like so -

```
// to terminate the worker thread
bEndThread = true;
SetEvent(hDoSomething);

// wait for worker thread to die
WaitForSingleObject(hWorkerThreadHandle, dwSomeSuitableTimeOut);
```

In some cases, we've used two events (one for work, one for termination) and `WaitForMultipleObjects` instead, but the general pattern is the same.

So, looking at replacing the `volatile bool` with a C++11 standard equivalent, is it as simple as replacing this

```
volatile bool bEndThread = false;
```

with this?

```
std::atomic<bool> bEndThread = false;
```

I'm sure it will work, but it doesn't seem enough. Also, it doesn't affect the case where we use two events and no `bool`.

Note, I'm not intending to replace all this legacy stuff with the [PPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx) and/or [Concurrency Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504870.aspx) equivalents because although we use these for new development, the legacy codebase is end-of-life and just needs to be compatible with the latest development tools (the original question I linked above shows where my concern arose).

Can someone give me a rough example of C++11 standard code we could use for this simple thread management pattern to rewrite our legacy code without too much refactoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it ain't broken don't fix it (especially if this is a legacy code base)

1. VS style volatile will be around for a few more years. Given that
   MFC isn't dead this won't be dead any time soon. A cursory Google
   search says you can control it with [`/volatile:ms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/12a04hfd.aspx).
2. Atomics might do the job of volatile, especially if this is a counter
   there might be little performance overhead.
3. Many Windows native functions have different performance characteristics when compared to their C++11 implementation. For example, Windows TimerQueues and Multimedia have precision that is not possible to achieve with C++11.

   For example `::sleep_for(5)`
   will sleep for 15 (and not 5 or 6). This can be solved with a mysterious
   call to `timeSetPeriod`. Another example is that unlocking on a condition variable can be slow to respond. Interfaces to fix these aren't exposed to C++11 on Windows.

Comment: Thanks - the `/volatile:ms` thing was what prompted this question (I linked to an earlier question) because the advice I got there suggested I *should* "fix" it. I'm just concerned that the next Visual Studio might break it if we don't make it slightly more compliant. Equally happy to do nothing though :-)

Comment: "have precision that is not possible to achieve with C++11" - could you elaborate why is this impossible? Bugs in VS implementation?

Comment: Add this to the list "header's high_resolution_clock does not have high resolution" -  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/